# problem with the dimension of matrices for neural network

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I wrote this code:

```
import numpy as np

INPUT_DIM = 8
OUTPUT_DIM = 10
H_DIM = 25
ALPHA = 0.0001
NUM_EPOCHS = 250

W1 = np.random.randn(INPUT_DIM, H_DIM)
b1 = np.random.randn(H_DIM)
W2 = np.random.randn(H_DIM, OUTPUT_DIM)
b2 = np.random.randn(OUTPUT_DIM)
-------------------------------------------------------------


def forward(x, y):
  t1 = x @ W1 + b1
  print(t1)
  h1 = relu(t1)
  print(h1.T)
  t2 = h1 @ W2 + b2
  z = softmax(t2)
  E = cross_entropy(z, y)
  return z, E, h1

def backward(z, y):
  y_full = to_full(y, OUTPUT_DIM)
  dE_dt2 = z - y_full
  dE_dW2 = h1.T @ dE_dt2
  dE_db2 = dE_dt2
  dE_dh1 = dE_dt2 @ W2.T
  dE_dt1 = dE_dh1 * relu_deriv(t1)
  dE_dW1 = x.T @ dE_dt1
  dE_db1 = dE_dt1
  return dE_dW1, dE_db1, dE_dW2, dE_db2

def update(dE_dW1, dE_db1, dE_dW2, dE_db2):
  W1 = W1 - ALPHA * dE_dW1
  b1 = b1 - ALPHA * dE_db1
  W2 = W2 - ALPHA * dE_dW2
  b2 = b2 - ALPHA * dE_db2
-------------------------------------------------------------------

for i in range(NUM_EPOCHS):
  for i in range(len(data)):
    x, y = data[i]
    z, E, h1 = forward(x, y)
    dE_dW1, dE_db1, dE_dW2, dE_db2 = backward(z, y)
    update(dE_dW1, dE_db1, dE_dW2, dE_db2)
```

in line: `dE_dW2 = h1.T @ dE_dt2`, i got error:
`ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 1 is different from 25)`

I know the rules for matrix multiplication, but still I don’t understand why the error occurs.
`h1` has 1 row ==> `h1.T` has 1 column, matrix `dE_dt2` has 1 row, which means multiplication should be possible.

Comment: Can you print the size of all the variables before doing any operation on them at the beginning of the function ?

Comment: You tagged this as ml.  Why?